# How to include an if-else condition in fetch API request?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, fetch

I am trying to make a discord bot that sends memes. I want a filter for NSFW images. The API I'm using gives `nsfw: true/false` in the response.
Here is my code

```
async function getMeme() {
  subreddit = memeSubreddits[Math.floor(Math.random() * memeSubreddits.length)];
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme/${subreddit}`);
    const data = await res.json();
    return data["url"];
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

I want to do something like

```
while (data["nsfw"]===true){
    //make fetch request again
}
```

I'm sending this meme as a message in discord as

```
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
  if (message.content === "-meme") {
    getMeme().then((meme) => message.channel.send(meme));
  }
});
```

Can I check for the NSFW condition here and say "the image you requested is NSFW"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `getMeme` a recursive function.

```
async function getMeme() {
    subreddit = memeSubreddits[Math.floor(Math.random() * memeSubreddits.length)];
    try {
        const res = await fetch(`https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme/${subreddit}`);
        const data = await res.json();
        if (data.nsfw) return getMeme();
        else return data.url;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

I'd also highly recommend catching errors in the caller, rather than catching in `getMeme` itself (which will result in errors resulting in a resolved Promise that resolves to `undefined`).

```
function getMeme() {
    const subreddit = memeSubreddits[Math.floor(Math.random() * memeSubreddits.length)];
    return fetch(`https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme/${subreddit}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            if (data.nsfw) return getMeme();
            else return data.url;
        });
}
```

```
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    if (message.content === "-meme") {
        getMeme()
            .then((meme) => message.channel.send(meme))
            .catch((error) => {
                // handle errors here
            });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance, I was trying the same thing with data[nsfw] and data[url] but it gave me weird errors about not being able to send empty messages etc. Can you explain why that happened?
Also, I'd like to send the name of the subreddit (given as data.subreddit) in the discord message. If I return url and subreddit as string the url gets sent as string above the picture in discord. How can I do that without url showing?

Comment: `data[nsfw]` and `data[url]` will only work if `nsfw` and `url` are identifiers - which they aren't (it sounds like), they're property names, so you should use dot notation. `data.url` etc. If you want to send something else, why not just return the whole data object? `return data` and then access its properties when sending `.then((meme) => { /* access properties of meme here */ })`

Comment: Another way is putting it in a string, like this: `data["url"]`